# Why does Fusion Middleware forwarding cause issues with my Spring Security authentication process?

Tags: spring, spring-security, middleware, weblogic11g

We have Fusion Middleware set up to handle our certificates.  It's configured on port 443 and forwards its requests after handling the certification process to an instance of weblogic 11g set up on port 8001.  That instance handles the authentication and returns the response through Middleware. We're using Spring 2.5.6 & Spring Security 2.0.4.  It's a flex-based web application. Using firebug/firefox, I was able to verify that the server handles the authentication request properly, and attempts to return my loginSuccess.htm (configured via `org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter` in my spring security config file) but I can see it's a 302 forward, it's error'd with a status from firebug saying Aborted.

Also to note, the authentication and application work fine on a standalone instance of weblogic; it's when we introduced the Fusion Middleware piece in between the web application and the client that we started to run into the authentication issues.

Here's a snippet of my AuthenticationProcessingFilter config entry:

```
<bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/loginFailure.htm"/>
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/loginSuccess.htm"/>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login.htm"/>
        <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/>
        <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />
        <property name="usernameParameter" value="username"/>
        <property name="passwordParameter" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

Any insight would be useful.  We introduced Fusion Middleware since it's Oracle's recommended production approach; we were having issues with certificates beforehand.

Comment: FYI - i'm starting to potentially narrow down the issue.  When hitting the url, our log-in uses https://[domain]/[context]/login.htm currectly, but the forwarding through authentication is returning http://[domain]/[context]/loginSuccess.htm instead of https.

Answer (score 0):

dvuke - using Oracle Fusion Middleware the redirection can be handled via the app server - so essentially there would be no need to make changes in your spring filter.

This approach using a permanent redirect attribute in your httpd.conf file may fix the issue you describe. So any redirection in your code could be forced to always be served up over https.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://server-name
    Redirect permanent /contextRoot https://server-name/contextRoot
</VirtualHost>
```

At least an avenue to look into!